# Harry Potter fanfiction where Harry is found abused and taken in by Snape

Tags: story-identification, harry-potter, fan-fiction

Harry is found abused and is taken in by Snape, then later on Harry is tortured by Voldemort and Lucius with needles and becomes blind. Eventually Snape adopts Harry and Draco. Dumbledore is a good guy and Lucius and Voldemort are really bad guys if I remember correctly it had a lot of chapters. I will give several cookies to the person who can find it.

Comment: Is it possibly this one? https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/199741/harry-potter-fanfic-where-harrys-abuse-by-the-dursleys-is-discovered-by-snape-a?r=SearchResults

Comment: Man HP fanfics are disturbing.....And that's saying a lot coming from someone who's part of ASOIAF fandom.

Comment: Its not that one where he is under the desk even though I did read that one.

Comment: _Dumbledore is a good guy and Lucius and Voldemort are really bad guys if I remember correctly_ - sure you're not thinking of the actual books?

Comment: Why is the question so downvoted?

Answer (score 2):

Faith... I knew the fic as soon as I read the question. Well, I knew I had read it a LONG time ago and loved it. I also knew I'd read it on FFnet and saved it as a favorite all those years ago. Guess what? It's not on FFnet anymore!!

But never fear!! A quick Google search for Snape adopts blind Harry fanfic and there it was!! So happy the author posted it on AO3! So, for your reading pleasure, I give you the series still in progress (yes, the author is currently writing the 3rd story in the series)...

[Like None Other](https://archiveofourown.org/series/41198)

Have fun!!

And a note for marcellothearcane: If you read HP fanfic at all, you'll know that there are enough stories out there that explore aspects of Rowling's "Good" and "Bad" characters that the qualifier in Faith's question was not out of place.